# Create pick list from different table in combobox wpf ef6

Tags: wpf, combobox

Right up front, I am a newbie.  I am creating a window with many comboboxes functioning as pick lists.  I have code behind xaml and auto generated files in a wpf ef6 application.  I have a table (InspectionTypes) with InspectionsID (Int) and InspectionName (String) properties.  In my Estimates window, I have a combobox that I desire to list and view/select an InspectionTypeName and store the InspectionsID in the record.

Here is my XAML portion for the combobox:

```
{           <ComboBox x:Name="inspectionType1ComboBox" 
                  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Width="200" Margin="3"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="InspectionType1">
            <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ComboBox>
}
```

I have been attempting to use a LINQ query and an ObservableCollection.  Currently, I am receiving the exception: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Number.StringToNumber(string, System.Globalization.NumberStyles, ref System.Number.NumberBuffer, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo, bool)
    System.Number.ParseInt32(string, System.Globalization.NumberStyles, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)
    string.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(System.IFormatProvider)
    System.Convert.ChangeType(object, System.Type, System.IFormatProvider)
    MS.Internal.Data.SystemConvertConverter.Convert(object, System.Type, object, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
    MS.Internal.Data.DynamicValueConverter.Convert(object, System.Type, object, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.VerifyEqual(object, System.Type, object, MS.Internal.Data.DynamicValueConverter)
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.FindItemWithValue(object, out int)
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectItemWithValue(object, bool)
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnItemsChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)

code behind:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource estimatesViewSource = 
           ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("estimatesViewSource")));
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource inspectionTypesViewSource = 
            ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource) 
            (this.FindResource("inspectionTypesViewSource")));
        context.Estimates.Load();
        estimatesViewSource.Source = context.Estimates.Local;
        inspectionTypesViewSource.Source = context.InspectionTypes.Local;
        FillComboBoxes();
    }
    private void FillComboBoxes()
    {
        MIDatabase01Entities1 db = new MIDatabase01Entities1();

        //var ItemList = (from d in db.InspectionTypes select new { d.InspectionTypesID, 
             d.InspectionTypeName }).ToList();
        var observablelist = new ObservableCollection<InspectionType>(db.InspectionTypes);

        inspectionType1ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "InspectionTypeName";
        inspectionType1ComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "InspectionTypesID";
        inspectionType1ComboBox.SelectedValue = "InspectionTypesID";
        //inspectionType1ComboBox.ItemsSource = ItemList;
        inspectionType1ComboBox.ItemsSource = observablelist;
    }
```

I have been trying to find an answer for weeks without success.  Could you please assist?

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the combobox from xaml.cs using ItemsSource in the method. You can make a property for the same and bind it in xaml. This issue is coming because you are assigning data before the view is rendered.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<InspectionType> observablelist { get; set; 

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource cvs = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("cvs")));
        DataContext = this;
        FillComboBoxes();
    }

    private void FillComboBoxes()
    {

        observablelist = new ObservableCollection<InspectionType>();
        observablelist.Add(new InspectionType()
        {
            InspectionTypeName = "ABC",
            InspectionTypesID = 1
        });

    }
}
```

xaml.cs

```
      <Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    xmlns:dat="clr- 
       namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=PresentationFramework"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="500" 
    Loaded="Window_Loaded">
   <Window.Resources>

    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding observablelist}"
                          x:Key="cvs">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="InspectionTypeName" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="InspectionTypesID" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
             DisplayMemberPath="InspectionTypeName"
             Name="lb">
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <x:Static Member="GroupStyle.Default" />
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
    </ListBox>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="2"
              Height="100"
              AllowDrop="True"
              Width="100"
              DisplayMemberPath="InspectionTypeName"
              SelectedValuePath="InspectionTypesID"
              ItemsSource="{Binding observablelist}"></ComboBox>


  </Grid>
 </Window>
```

Comment: I have made the modifications you suggested, where I expected to see "ABC" in the list of the combo-box.  It presents a blank list.  What I need is the list from the InspectionTypes table.  Adding each item as suggested would not be acceptable.  When I put a break-point  at the closing bracket of the FillComboBoxes() method and look at the item count it is zero.  InspectionsID is a foreign key in the Estimates table and is the primary key in the InspectionTypes table.  Here is the current section of code for the code behind:

Comment: While looking at the data, I can see that there is a single entry into the observableist displaying the added data.  I do not understand why it does not contain the data from the InspectionTypes table also.  The .Add method should add to the existing list.  I do not understand what the last line does. " inspectionType1ComboBox = new ComboBox();"  The  combobox is bound to observablelist but, no items are listed in the data - confusing.  Should it not show the added item in the items list?  I do understand that the data needs to be present before rendering - appreciate that info.

Comment: Update:  I have the observableList functioning with the proper number of items in the list.  The combobox item list is null however.  I set the binding exactly as you indicated but the ItemsSource - null and ItemsCount=0.

Comment: Can you share your code? Sorry the last line is not needed at all. I hope you have given data context properly.

Comment: How do I post the code?  Should I edit the question?

Comment: private void FillComboBoxes()
        {
            var result = from p in context.InspectionTypes select p;
            observableList = new ObservableCollection<InspectionType>(result);
            inspectionType1ComboBox = new ComboBox();
        }

Comment: <ComboBox x:Name="inspectionType1ComboBox"
              Grid.Column="2"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Height="Auto"
              Width="200"
              Margin="3"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              DisplayMemberPath="InspectionTypeName"
              SelectedValuePath="InspectionTypesID"
              ItemsSource="{Binding observablelist}">
            </ComboBox>

Comment: public ObservableCollection<InspectionType> observableList { get; set; }

        public EstimatesScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            estimatesViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(FindResource("estimatesViewSource")));
            DataContext = this;
            FillComboBoxes();

Comment: I was looking to see if I could add the InspeectionTypes into the data context.

Comment: Your code is working fine with me. Just that I have not used CollectionViewSource. And can't analyse how is that being used in your xaml section. If you can remove that and check.

Comment: Check the edited answer. and try for a simple implementation first. then go with what you require.

Comment: The problem as I see it is that the observablecollection is not being applied to the combobos.items. I have a Word file with all code, data and screenshots that I can send.